# How can I remove the right side of this string?

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript I have a String
`"Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1"`

I just want the `"Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"` when this gets generated. Is there a way I can use the `"|"` as a delimiter and remove everything (include it) out of the string?

EDIT:

I tried using Left, here is an example of my code

```
For Each objOperatingSystem in colItems
   strOSName = Left(objOperatingSystem.name,InStr("|"))
Next
```

I get an error,

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'InStr'

Comment: I'm fairly certain VBScript has reference documentation with a list of string functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
strOSName = TRIM(Left(objOperatingSystem.name,InStr(objOperatingSystem.name,"|")-1))
```

For safety you may want to try

```
if InStr(objOperatingSystem.name,"|") then
    strOSName = TRIM(Left(objOperatingSystem.name,InStr(objOperatingSystem.name,"|")-1))
end if
```

Just because, here is another method:

```
dim yourString
dim anArray
dim strOSName 
yourString = "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1"
anArray = Split(yourString,"|")
strOSName = TRIM(anArray(0))
```

Comment: there still is a trailing blank.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - If you see a trailing blank edit the answer and FIX it..thats the point of the site to help people.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner It took me a little while to figure out you were referring to the white space in the variable. I'll throw in the Trim function you're asking for, to please you.

Comment: @JonH In my opinion an author is responsible for his contribution; I would never change other peoples texts.

Comment: @DanielCook thanks for taking extra care (for the record: I upvoted your answer *before* I pointed out the blank)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Split function in vbscript to split a string to a special character. Split function breaks a string into an array. Use the following:

Split("Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1", "|", "-1", "-1")(0)

If you find it little awkward you may use:

dim arr

arr = Split("Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1", "|", "-1", "-1")

myStr = arr(0)

It will work for sure.